# PHP can't connect to local MariaDB server using TCP

Tags: php, mysqli, macports, mariadb

My laptop (which runs os x) had a little kernel panic over the weekend, so I had to forcefully restart it. –Unfortunately, a PHP app I'm developing can't connect to the MariaDB server running on it anymore using TCP, returning this pretty error message here:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: [2002] Connection refused (trying to connect via tcp://127.0.0.1:3306)
```

I obtained MariaDB, Apache and PHP through MacPorts and I ran `port upgrade outdated` a few days ago, but my code hasn't changed at all.

Connecting to MariaDB with Sequel Pro using sockets works.

Comment: Are you able to log in from the comand line?

Comment: Yes, by using a local socket. But I figured this out already. (See answer below.) –Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparantly, the newest version of MariaDB added `skip-networking` to my.cnf. After commenting the line out and restarting the MariaDB service, everything seems to be working again.